Super methods in service class In Floating Pop up
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

    LinearLayout ly = new LinearLayout(context);
    ly.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    ly.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    wm.addView(ly, params);

}

backpress how i am did Super methods in service class In Floating Pop up in android

back button,home button, power button was clicked or whenever activity or view or windows was changed.


I don't see a question. Please [edit] and clarify what you want to know.
